# $f: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n $ holomorphic vanishing on $\mathbb R^n$ is $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n $ be a holomorphic function, and let $B$ be an open ball centered in $0$.

> If $f$ vanishes on $B \cap \mathbb R^n$ then $f\equiv 0$.

When $n=1$ since the zeros must be isolated the claim is quite simple. I have no idea on how to proceed for $n > 1$.

Comment: Is this open ball centred on a real point?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't know, we can if we want, in the problem I'm studying this is the case! Is that necessary?

Comment: An arbitrary ball may miss $\Bbb R^n$ completely.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Choose any coordinate system on your ball. It should be true totally generally. The zero locus of $f$ should be a complex hypersurface, and this contains no totally real $n$-dimensional affine space.

Comment: @TedShifrin Without the condition that $B\cap\Bbb R^n$ be nonempty, it's not even true for $n=1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin He is right! Pick a point $p = (z_1, \cdots, z_n)$, suppose every component has imaginary part not $0$, by continuity a small ball has coordiniates with imaginary part not $0$.

Comment: I'm saying you can choose an arbitrary affine coordinate system on $\Bbb C^n$ to make the problem interesting.

Comment: I'd say the Taylor series of your function at $Z = 0$ is identically $0$. Then use that holomorphic functions are analytic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take a simple case: Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C^2$ and $f = 0$ on $\mathbb R^2.$ For each fixed $x \in \mathbb R,$ the entire function $g_x$ on $\mathbb C$ given by $g_x(z)= f(z,x)$ equals $0$ on the real axis. By the identity principle, $g_x\equiv 0.$ In other words, $f\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb C \times \mathbb R.$

But then for each fixed $z\in \mathbb C,$ the entire function $h_z$ on $\mathbb C$ given by $h_z(w)= f(z,w),$ equals $0$ on the real axis. By the identity principle, $h_z\equiv 0.$ In other words, $f\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C.$